# How is 見送りなんてよかったのに used here?

Tags: readings, reading-comprehension

[image]

Context: The characters are walking together after going to a work thing.

I'm stumbled on this use of なんてなんてよかったのに here. From context I can gather the character is saying it was fine to not see him off?

Given his answer is "I was the one that called you during a holiday (so at least I can do this much) I know なんてよかったのに is used to express regret but I don't quite see why it would follow "Because it's cold"

Comment: Do you understand what 見送る means?

Answer (score 1):

- **見送り**: "send-off; seeing someone off"
- **なんて**: (used to make light of 見送り)
- **よかった**: "was unnecessary"

  - ["No, your taste is (not) good"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/73183/5010)
  - [How to respond to ポイントカードが宜しいですか。](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57911/5010)
  - [Don't understand the situation in a shin chan comic strip](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25914/5010)
  - [How to say "no thank you, I don't want / need it"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14613/5010)
- **のに**: (used to show regrettable feeling)

  - [What does のに mean at the end of this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42408/5010)

So a literal translation is "A send-off was not necessary, but..." but a natural translation would be "You didn't have to see me off".

Comment: Ah I see. It's the いい meaning for "no need" bit somehow it didn't register in my mind with the past form.